# Where does the space come from, and how to get rid of id?

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

Two Columns, text on the left side, a picture on the right. Does not sound difficult, but IE 11 inserts 4px of bottom padding, and I cannot find where it comes from and how to get rid of it.
Chrome, FF and Edge are behaving as expected (Red background is not visible below the text or the Image).
I tried to set a fixed height of 200px for the outer div, this works, but is not usable in the real rroject.

```css
.gray-2-columns {
  background: red;
  column-count: 2;
}

.gray-2-columns .text {
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
}

.gray-2-columns img {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="gray-2-columns">
  <div class="text">
    Text
  </div>
  <img width="300" height="200" alt="" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200?text=Red+line+below+here+in+IE" border="0">
</div>
```

Comment: I would use `flexbox` instead for this use-case. `columns` works best if you have an unknown number of items which you want to flow over two or more columns, like a 2-column menu or list

Comment: You're right @Giorgio, I should consider that. Right after understanding what's going on here :-D

Answer (score 2):

The `img` tag displays `inline` by default - use `display: inline-block;` or `display: block;` on the img tag.

Comment: Why is display:inline a reason for space below an element? 
When you check the same code with columns-count:1, there is no extra space below the (inline-)image.

Comment: because inline elements are aligned much like text is aligned, and it reacts on the `vertical-align` property. Eg. `vertical-align: bottom` will align the bottom of the element (the `img` in this particular case) with the bottom of the line. This will actually solve your problem as well, as by default an image is vertically aligned to the baseline (which is above the bottom of the line).

Comment: oh and using `display: inline-block` will _not_ help you, as `inline-block` elements are also aligned like text would. So it's either `vertical-align: bottom` or `display: block`

Comment: The snippet provided actually sets a `vertical-align:top` to the image to avoid the "baseline-problem". I don't see a difference in IE when changing this to `vertical-align:bottom`. 
`display:block` is a workaround which visually leads to a correct result.

Comment: Another problem with `display:block` is, that I cannot align the image anymore in horizontal direction via `text-align`

Comment: Inline blocks also have a `line-height`: that's where the spacing is coming from. To align center either try making the image an `inline-block` or if that fails, set it to `block` and use `margin: 0 auto;` style attribute.